# how do I get a substring in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a string that contains some text:

```
 <p>ProductImage [height:60]</p>
```

and I want to extract just the 60 from it?  The 60 is just an arbitrary value here

Comment: I would just cut off the first 24 characters and the last 5. Or use regex.

Comment: You need to make it clear if it's only in that particular case (<p>ProductImage [height:60]</p>) or if it should cover extracting a number out of any string.

Comment: extracting the number from any text with a pattern of [height:60], where 60 can be any numeric value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an NSScanner, or search using an NSRegularExpression.

```
NSScanner* sc = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
int num;
[sc scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] 
                   intoString:nil];
[sc scanInt:&num];
```

Or:

```
int num;
NSError* err = nil;
NSRegularExpression* r = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d+"
                                                                   options:0 
                                                                     error:&err];
// error-checking omitted
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in [r matchesInString:s 
                                               options:0 
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])])
    num = [[s substringWithRange: [match range]] intValue];
```