# How to get the substring of a string

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get substring of nsstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676106/how-to-get-substring-of-nsstring)
>   [how do I get a substring in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330663/how-do-i-get-a-substring-in-ios)

I am new to iphone.In my project i have a string such as chapter1 but actually i want the substring 1 only how it is possible.if any body know this please help me

Comment: Uh, read the spec for NSString, perhaps?

Comment: such a easy question to find on NSString reference https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nsstring+reference

Comment: Ctrl + F for "substring": https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `substringFromIndex:` or `substringToIndex:` methods of NSString. You can find the documentation for NSString [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Ex:

```
  NSString *string = @"Chapter1";  
  NSString *newString = [string subStringFromIndex: ([string length] - 1)]; // => "1"
```